# Performance bottleneck at target in informatica mapping

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica-powercenter

I have a informatica mapping wherein soft delete condition is as follows:

```
Pk_Src is null and Pk_Tgt is not null then set the active_flag to N.
```

Now based on this condition the mapping evaluated that there are 400k records which needs to be updated. Its a simple update but it is taking more than 3 hours using update strategy

Appreciate your valuable inputs.

Dex.

Comment: Can you share some logs? It appears to be really too long. Alternatively, use a temporary table to store IDs for soft-delete and run a post-SQL statement to apply this.

Answer (score 0):

How many records are on the table and how many indexes does active_flag appear in? If active_flag is in many indexes then you should consider dropping those indexes before the session starts and redefining them after the session ends. Have you looked through the session log to see which steps are taking time? There may be more beside the update query. Another strategy to try is increasing your commit interval to 500000 (so long as your db undo can withstand that)

Comment: 500K records are in Target and all have active flag...Will try to drop and recreate the indexes

Comment: Only 500k records in target... its possible something else is happening here... are you precaching lookups in the mapping? How long is the beginning section of the session log where you precache lookups taking

Comment: Session logs point to writer thread...So only bottleneck is at updating Target records

Answer (score 0):

In general you should expect very slow performance when doing updates/deletes from an infa mapping. 10-100 times slower than inserts. This is due to the fact that there is no ‘array’ based update/delete, and each update therefore needs to be handled separately and sequentially, and you end up in a situation where 90% if the time is spend sending handshakes back and forth. With inserts the handshakes is only being done for each ‘array-size’ records (say 10000) and the overhead is therefore negligible.

The best solutions I have found so far is:

1. use push down optimization (draw back is that mapping needs to be 100% push-downable, which means: no variable ports, and both source and target behind the same connection and much more)
2. use a stage/apply approach:
   In the pre-sql of the session, drop&create a STAGE table with all the keys you wish to delete
   Override the table name for your target to point to this STAGE table
   Let the mapping do inserts to the STAGE table
   In the post-sql do a 
   `Delete from TABLE where Exists (select * from STAGE where TABLE.ID=STAGE.ID)`

I hope you cal follow me